# gulp: pipe typescript output to mocha

Tags: typescript, gulp, mocha.js

I want to add mocha test to a TypeScript project. In `gulpfile.js` I pipe gulp-typescript and gulp-mocha tegether:

```
gulp.src(['./test/**/*.ts', './typings/tsd.d.ts'])
  .pipe(typescript())
  .pipe(mocha());
```

Mocha reports error `Error: Cannot find module '.../myproject/test/case1.js'`.

Searched on Google, all examples I found are saving typescript transpiler output into temporary files and then run with mocha. I also noticed in gulp-mocha document it says "you can't have any plugins before it":

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('test.js', {read: false})
        // gulp-mocha needs filepaths so you can't have any plugins before it 
        .pipe(mocha({reporter: 'nyan'}));
});
```

However, one benefit of gulp is using stream to omit temporary files. How can I pipe transpiler output to mocha? Or it's impossible for mocha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a question 3 years ago. I post my own answer to conclude it.

My solution was not to use any build tool like Gulp, but use [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) directly. And also with the help of [scripty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scripty) I can write build script in any scripting language, e.g. shell script or javascript.

Here is an example: https://github.com/aleung/node-anyid/blob/master/package.json

Reference:
[Using Npm Scripts as a Build Tool](https://deliciousbrains.com/npm-build-script/)

Answer (score 0):

Until you pipe the typescript compiler output to your destination location using gulp.dest, you would not have the output files available for mocha to run your tests. The below would work as per my tests.

```
gulp.src(['./test/**/*.ts', './typings/tsd.d.ts'])
  .pipe(typescript())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
  .pipe(mocha());
```